# filtering the ansible playbook output

Tags: linux, filter, ansible

I have output of an ansible playbook for which i need to apply fileters in such a way to proceed with next tasks. Please find the below output.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
"results": [
    {
        "actions": {
            "namespaces": {}, 
            "state": "present", 
            "xpath": "/Storage/SSL/KeyStorePath"
        }, 
        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
        "changed": false, 
        "pod": 1, 
        "failed": false, 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "mount": true, 
                "input_type": "yaml",
            }
        }, 
        "item": "100.108.22.102", 
        "msg": "found 1 nodes"
    }, 
    {
        "actions": {
            "namespaces": {}, 
            "state": "present", 
            "xpath": "/Storage/SSL/KeyStorePath"
        }, 
        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
        "changed": false, 
        "pod": 0, 
        "failed": false, 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "mount": true, 
                "input_type": "yaml",
            }
        }, 
        "item": "100.108.22.103", 
        "msg": "found 0 nodes"
    }
]
```

}

Here, i want the next task to be executed when the node respective pod value is 1 if the pod value of the node is 0 then the next task should not run on the respective node ip.

Please assist ..

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*Execute next task when the node's respective pod value is 1*"**

A: There are many ways how to proceed with the next task. For example, given the variable *results*

1. Use [delegate_to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#controlling-where-tasks-run-delegation-and-local-actions) and loop selected items

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 'Task is running on {{ item.item }}'
      loop: "{{ results|selectattr('pod', 'eq', 1)|list }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ item.item }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost -> 100.108.22.102] => (item=100.108.22.102) => 
  msg: Task is running on 100.108.22.102
```

---

2. Create a list of selected hosts and test the host is in the list

```yaml
- hosts: 100.108.22.102,100.108.22.103
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Task is running on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in pods
      vars:
        pods: "{{ results|
                  selectattr('pod', 'eq', 1)|
                  map(attribute='item')|
                  list }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
ok: [100.108.22.102] => 
  msg: Task is running on 100.108.22.102
skipping: [100.108.22.103]
```

---

3. Use [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) to create an inventory group in the first play and use it in the second one

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: '{{ item }}'
        groups: pods_enabled
      loop: "{{ results|
                selectattr('pod', 'eq', 1)|
                map(attribute='item')|
                list }}"

- hosts: pods_enabled
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Task is running on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [add_host] ****
changed: [localhost] => (item=100.108.22.102)

PLAY [pods_enabled] ****

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [100.108.22.102] => 
  msg: Task is running on 100.108.22.102

PLAY RECAP ****
100.108.22.102: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0   
localhost: ok=1 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Debug is listing the Ip's. But my question here is i want the next task to be run on those filtered IP's. How can we achive it..! @Vladimir Botka

Comment: Hi, You're welcome. I've added the next example. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: The example looks good but the challenge here is i am running the playbook on localhost and few of the tasks on Inverntory file because of which it's getting skipped. so not sure, how i can get it.! @Vladimir Botka

Comment: I've added one more example. If you have more issues open new questions. Make it [mre]. The expected output should be part of the question too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `with_items` and `when` in your next task as below

```yaml
- name: validate pod value
  debug:
    msg: "The pod value is 1"
  with_items: "{{ your_var.results }}"
  when: item.pod == "1"
```